# OSGi implementation for .NET

Tags: .net, plugins, osgi

Is there work on implementing a .NET version of the OSGi plugin architecture (or something similar)? I have only found [this](http://www-adele.imag.fr/Les.Publications/intConferences/CCNC2006Esc.pdf) paper, but no real library. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know much about OSGi, but you should take a look at [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF) project. I believe it provides some subset of functionalities of OSGi.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a commercial product named [UIOSP(XAUI Open Service Platform)](http://uishell.com/ProductShow.asp?ID=94) which is the .NET implemented based-on OSGi specification R4 by a startup software company, Xi'an UI, in China. 
Well, now only Chinese version available.  You may try contact with e-mail (uishell@uishell.com).

Comment: [here](http://osgi4net.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/saying-hello/) got one English introduction of there product.

Comment: Yeah... it doesn't specify which spec's or what version of the spec it conforms to. I am a bit hesitant to use it.

Comment: 99% based on OSGi spec V4.