# Is there a way to develop Eclipse plugins using .NET?

Tags: .net, eclipse-plugin

I know it may sound like a weird question, but is there any .NET friendly way to develop eclipse plugins?

- Java wrappers to .NET components?
- .NET implementation of OSGI?
- Translators? Code generators?
- .NET API to automate Plugin creation?

For example, a company specializing in .NET that has some .NET based IDE-like tools wishes to move some tools to Eclipse, is there any way of reusing any of the work done? or must it be written from scratch in Java? (or any other JVM based language)

If there is nothing out there, is it possible to create a wrapper to embed .NET controls (Windows only or using Mono) inside an eclipse plugin?

I found these relevant resources: [OSGi implementation for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864974/osgi-implementation-for-net)

[Is there a way to create Eclipse plugins with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571235/is-there-a-way-to-create-eclipse-plugins-with-python)

(Which suggest that the answer is "no", but the question is: can it be done in theory?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI will not be portable. Eclipse has its own API that will need to be adhered to, and that's just not going to be the same as Visual Studio's API. Sorry.

But the logic, any raw data processing your plugin does could port fairly well. You could even put the logic into a COM component and call it from Java, or use [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/index.htm) or [JNI4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/). Whether or not the logic code will port depends entirely on how you structured your code originally, however, so take the previous sentences with a grain of salt.